# BlocProvider not found

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-cubit

For some reason when I was trying to show an alert dialog which needs a cubit created previously the cubit is not found.

As mentioned before when i am trying to provide a cubit with BlocProvider.value(value: context.read()), child: ...; to an alertDialog it wont find it...

```dart
SlidableAction(
          backgroundColor: block.sperrgrund != null ? Colors.orange : Colors.green,
          icon: block.sperrgrund != null ? Icons.lock : Icons.lock_open,
          onPressed: block.sperrgrund == null ? (context) {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return BlocProvider.value(
                  value: context.read<DropdownCubit<Sperrgrund>>(),
                  child: SperrenPopup(
                    block: block as ZinkScan,
                    cubit: this.cubit!,
                  ),
                );
              }
              );
            } : null
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```dart
SlidableAction(
          backgroundColor: block.sperrgrund != null ? Colors.orange : Colors.green,
          icon: block.sperrgrund != null ? Icons.lock : Icons.lock_open,
          onPressed: block.sperrgrund == null ? (context) {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) {
                return BlocProvider.value(
                  value: context.read<DropdownCubit<Sperrgrund>>(),
                  child: SperrenPopup(
                    block: block as ZinkScan,
                    cubit: this.cubit!,
                  ),
                );
              }
              );
            } : null
        )
```

So, instead of the `context` provided by `builder` it will be using the `context` of its parent to scope the blockProvider and wrap `SlidableAction` with `Builder` if you have defined the `BlockProvider` inside the same build method from where you are trying to show the dialog.